# Two Activity at top of stack even after launchMode is singleTop

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am opening an Activity when a button is pressed. However, if user presses this button twice fast enough my activity launches two times. To prevent that I added `launchMode: singleTop` in manifest and also added this flag to launching intent.

But still the behaviour is same. I am not looking to prevent double clicking by using handler threads or enabling disabling it. I wish to know why `singleTop` is not working in this case.

code in Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

Intent

```
val intent = Intent(context, MyActivity::class.java)
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
activity?.startActivityFromFragment(this, intent, REQUEST_CODE)
```

**Update**

Upon more investigation I found that `startActivityForResult` is not respecting the flag. `startActivityFromFragment` calls `startActivityForResult`
I wrote a [sample which reproduces this here](https://github.com/abhishekBansal/SingleTopIssue)

Comment: Post your Manifest file and code where you are calling newIntent.

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi Added code

Comment: Please provide an answer with your findings and accept your answer. This will remove the question from the list of open questions and may help others who have a similar problem.

Comment: @DavidWasser I havn't found a solid answer as of now.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your previous comment. The correct way to do this is to usexa boolean flag to ensure you do not call startActivity() more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use signeTop. You can use any delay method on your button so that it won't get clicked immediately next time. If you are using rx android you can use below method. or you can create your own simple logic.

```
RxView.clicks(view).throttleFirst(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(empty -> {
            // action on click
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about this solution but I feel that launching a thread for a simple click is little too much.

Comment: I think everything is done in same thread which is main thread.

Comment: `throttleLast` operates on `computation` scheduler by default
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html

Comment: moreover `RxView` is not available in `RxAndroid` its part of RxBindings

Comment: I don't have machine right now I'll look into your code when I get my hand on my machine

Comment: sure, I have added more details and a sample which reproduces the result to original question. Thanks.

Comment: As described in this post juejin.im/post/5a76af275188257a836c0885 The problem is startActivityForResult it does not respect the flag.  startActivity works just fine. I tried on Android 8.0

Comment: I think `startActivityForResult` start a new Task and does not run on your current task

Comment: Probably! do you have a reference?

Comment: @Sunny `startActivityForResult()` definitely does NOT start a new task.

Comment: I was just guessing. please share if  you found the reason?